# How to execute an awk call with mixed quotes in R?

Tags: r, awk

I need to run `awk` from within R to [add spaces at the end of each line of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41000523), to ensure that it has consistently a fixed width throughout. Like this:

```
$ cat -e file
1$
12$
123$
1234$
$ awk '{printf "%-10s\n", $0}' file | cat -e
1         $
12        $
123       $
1234      $
12345     $
```

However I have trouble doing this from within R. [How to correctly escape system calls from inside R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985481/how-to-correctly-escape-system-calls-from-inside-r) deals with something similar, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
> ' awk \'{printf "%-180s\n", $0}\' file '
[1] " awk '{printf \"%-180s\n\", $0}' file "
> system(' awk \'{printf "%-180s\n", $0}\' file ')
awk: cmd. line:1: {printf "%-180s
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ unterminated string
awk: cmd. line:1: {printf "%-180s
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ syntax error
```

I also tried `system(" awk '{printf \"%-180s\n\", $0}' file ")`, with the exact same error. I'm not sure why this fails, but it seems to be related to the mixed quotes. Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: This completely blows me away. Are you saying that R is unable to do this without calling a system command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is right, you just need to escape the `\` in `\n`. Since it is handled by the `printf()` inside `awk` you need to escape it to let it be treated literally

```
system("awk '{printf \"%-10s\\n\",$0}' file")
```

or with a variable

```
awkcommand <- "awk '{printf \"%-10s\\n\",$0}' file"
system(awkcommand)
```

Comment: Well, that was silly of me, and *now* the error message makes more sense... Thanks!